# How do I know if my Australia ETA is approved?

Tags: australia, eta

I received a email saying that I would need to check again within 12 hours. However when I check my ETA status at http://www.eta.immi.gov.au/

I got this:

> You have a current ETA to travel to Australia.
>
> The Australian Electronic Travel Authority System has reported the
>   following data and conditions apply to your ETA:
>
> ```
> Expiry Date    05 JUN 2013
> Period of Stay     3 Months
> Number of Entries  Multiple
> Employment Conditions  Employment Prohibited
> ```
>
> The Expiry Date of the ETA is the latest date on which you may enter
>   Australia with this ETA. The Period of Stay is the longest time you
>   may spend in Australia on any one visit. The Number of Entries is the
>   number of times you may enter Australia with this ETA.

Am I approved or not?

Answer (score 13):

> You have a current ETA to travel to Australia.

Yes, you have been approved.

Answer (score 6):

Odds are, emails get batched up, so by the time the email was sent out, you were already approved.  And as you've seen on the site, it told you that it was approved for entry.

Note that while the expiry date is 5 June 2013, naturally if you enter earlier as planned, you can only stay for 3 months at a time.

Long story short?  **You have a current ETA to travel to Australia.**